# Which method compiler executes first?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, increment, post-increment

```
int i = 10, j = 5, k;

k = f(++i) + g(++i) + j+ 25;
```

Is `f(++i)` or `g(++i)` is computed first?

and how can you know without running the program?

Assuming `f` and `g` are similar to

```
int f(int a)
{ return a; }
```

How does the order change depending on the compiler?

Comment: Did you try to run it and see? Or try to Debug the program?

Comment: Read this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081393/is-the-left-to-right-order-of-operations-guaranteed-in-java

Comment: @sanA's link is a very good one to read.  My answer is true for your case, but may not be for others.

Comment: "Which method compiler executes fist?" Neither. The compiler doesn't execute anything.

Comment: Sorry maybe my question is worded wrong. I meant to ask which is calculated first. Im not sure if that clarifies anything though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which method compiler executes fist?

It is not the compiler that executes instructions but the JVM.

And the Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators are evaluated from left to right by the JVM. From [JLS Sec 15.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7):

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.

About whether the compiler may reorganize the order of equivalent expressions in the compiled class, it may be the case for "optimization" reasons. These may change from one Java version to another one, so generally you should even not consider it.

Comment: You're right that the compiler doesn't execute instruction, but it's still the compiler who determines the evaluation order (well, the standard determines the evaluation order, but it's the compiler who implements that part of the standard), not the JVM. The JVM just executes the instructions in whichever order the compiler generated them - from top to bottom. There's no left and right at the JVM level.

Answer (score 0):

Unless otherwise modified, evaluation is left-to-right.  So in this case, f(++i) goes first.

EDIT: As @sanA points out, there could be compiler optimizations.  In your case it's unlikely (but not impossible) since your functions probably qualify as side effects.