# Evaluation order in Java

Tags: java, recursion

So I have this code for the *Fibonacci sequence*:

```
int fibonacci(int i, int[] memo) {
   if (i == 0 || i == 1) return i;

   if (memo[i] == 0) {
      memo[i] = fibonacci(i - 1, memo) + fibonacci(i - 2, memo);
   }

   return(memo[i]);
}
```

My question is: `fibonacci(i-1, memo)` will always be evaluated before `fibonacci(i-2, memo)` correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the left-to-right order of operations guaranteed in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081393/is-the-left-to-right-order-of-operations-guaranteed-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct, from **left to right**.

First you will completely traverse the recursion with the left argument `fibonacci(i - 1, memo)` after that, when it moves the recursion tree up again, each time the right argument will get computed, again with a full recursive tree.

A quick search yield this image illustrating the process:

[image: Recursive Fibonacci computation order]

Note that many values are often computed multiple times. Your current approach tries to optimize this by caching results inside an array `memo`.